# Is there a way to auto remount a drive without a reboot

Tags: drive

I have an external drive that apparently won't automount anymore.  If I didn't want to restart the machine.  Is there a way to automount the drive.

It shows up under /dev/sdb1 if I do:

fstab -l

Comment: If you think it should automount, find the reason why it doesn't, and if there is a problem, solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it "automounting" but you can manually mount the drive. try making a directory for it to mount to:

```
    sudo mkdir /media/name_of_drive
```

Then mount it with

```
    sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/name_of_drive
```

Answer (score 1):

From man page of mount:

**mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]**

(usually given in a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose line contains the noauto keyword. Adding the -F option will make mount fork, so that the filesystems are mounted simultaneously.
When mounting a filesystem mentioned in fstab or mtab, it suffices to give only the device, or only the mount point.

The programs mount and umount maintain a list of currently mounted filesystems in the file /etc/mtab. If no arguments are given to mount, this list is printed.